# Javascript flipbook application not working in Chrome on Windows 7

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, compatibility

Hi. I have a problem with my current site that has me totally stymied.

I have implemented a javascript flipbook (like an ibook) on my website. It works in Firefox, Opera, Mac, on the iPad, etc., but not on Chrome Windows 7.  In Chrome Windows 7, when I click, the page turns, and then the application resets back to the original image. In Firefox, however, it works just fine.

I have scoured the code to find the solution, troubleshooted from different angles, but can't solve the problem.

You can view the site in its current condition here : http://www.cambrianvacation.co.uk/powersb

I have only just begun working on this site, and the flipbook just has dummy content, purely for the purpose of getting it to work, so please excuse that.

If anyone can diagnose the problem, I would be very grateful.

P.S. I have only been studying Javascript for a few months, and although I have a basic understanding, it's not enough to resolve this.

Comment: Any errors in the Chrome console? Does the same behavior occur in Chrome on other operating systems?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067565/javascript-flipbook-robustness

Answer (score 1):

It works perfectly fine for me in Windows 7 + Chrome.

Since Chrome is quite aggressive in it's caching policies, you might as well clear Chrome's cache and try again.

Comment: Problem is solved, I was testing in Chrome through Aptana,(which is what Ive always done). Through launching the site through the internal server there was a specific problem with Chrome, however in reality there was no problem with Chrome, in going straight to the server. Just testing through the specific run configurations in the software.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, if you go to their website over here: http://flippingbook.com/help/publisher-2/faq/launching-local-publication-in-google-chrome/ they have a guide on how to fix this issue. It is very not handy at all though because it will be fixing the problem for you only not for whoever visits your website.